# ARM objcopy results in empty binary file

Tags: gcc, arm, objcopy, eabi

How can I get `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` to copy/translate my `.axf` file into a `.bin` suitable for flashing to the device with `lm4tools`?

I have a ~20KB `.axf` file compiled and linked with `arm-none-eabi-*`. For anyone interested, this is with the Stellaris Launchpad.

I'm trying to modify the example provided with the [`stellaris-launchpad-template-gcc`](https://github.com/scompo/stellaris-launchpad-template-gcc) project to compile with C++ code. I've managed to get it to produce a `.axf` file in `elf32-littlearm` format (according to the `.lst` file), however when I try to do

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -v -O binary main.axf foo.bin
```

to translate it into a programmable file, the `.bin` file output has a size of 0 bytes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553153/elf-file-thinks-its-small-but-its-large-can-not-generate-bin-and-hex-files) describes a similar problem. I'm confident the `.axf` file is complete, so why isn't my `.bin` file being populated with anything? If I remove `-O binary`, the file is copied fine. The directory is writeable and all permissions are fine. I've tried searching both on SO and the rest of the internet with various terms, all of which turned up nothing of use. It seems nobody's had this problem before.

Running `arm-none-eabi-objdump -D main.axf` yields a dump of the file in what appears to be assembler:

```
main.axf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .debug_info:

00000000 <_end_text>:
       0:   00000082    andeq   r0, r0, r2, lsl #1
       4:   00000002    andeq   r0, r0, r2
       8:   01040000    mrseq   r0, (UNDEF: 4)
       c:   00000057    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr r0
      10:   00000c04    andeq   r0, r0, r4, lsl #24
      14:   00002300    andeq   r2, r0, r0, lsl #6
    ...
      28:   08010200    stmdaeq r1, {r9}
      2c:   00000015    andeq   r0, r0, r5, lsl r0
      30:   00410103    subeq   r0, r1, r3, lsl #2
      34:   32010000    andcc   r0, r1, #0
      38:   00000048    andeq   r0, r0, r8, asr #32
    ...
      48:   69050404    stmdbvs r5, {r2, sl}
      4c:   0500746e    streq   r7, [r0, #-1134]    ; 0x46e
      50:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
      54:   46430100    strbmi  r0, [r3], -r0, lsl #2
    ...
```

Is this correct, or am I not even compiling properly, seeing as this appears to be some kind of assembler?

Some info about the `.axf` file:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          20372 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         14
  Section header string table index: 11
```

After running `arm-none-eabi-readelf -lS main.axf`, no program headers are returned:

```
There are 14 section headers, starting at offset 0x4f94:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 000034 0019a6 00      0   0  1
  [ 2] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 0019da 0005ad 00      0   0  1
  [ 3] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 001f87 001796 00      0   0  1
  [ 4] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 003720 000088 00      0   0  8
  [ 5] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 0037a8 000130 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 0038d8 00077d 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 004055 000aa8 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 8] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 004afd 00003a 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 9] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 004b37 000039 00      0   0  1
  [10] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 004b70 000388 00      0   0  4
  [11] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 004ef8 00009a 00      0   0  1
  [12] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0051c4 000200 10     13  18  4
  [13] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0053c4 0000e0 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no program headers in this file.
```

Comment: @dwelch This is for an ARM chip, so I highly doubt it would become a multi-GB file, and opening the file in vim yields an empty file.

Comment: There are no program headers, no text or data sections, so `objcopy` is fine, the `.axf` file is incorrectly built.

Comment: @chill That much is apparent. Thanks for the hints. I think I'll open a new question as building the .axf file is out of this one's scope.

Comment: Are you using this linker script ? https://github.com/scompo/stellaris-launchpad-template-gcc/blob/master/LM4F.ld

Comment: Yes I am, however I've changed a couple of bits of the Makefile to support C++ files. Should I post the Makefile here?

Comment: No need. That linker script uses names like `.text.something`, `.data.something` for input sections, which misses `.text`, `.data`, `.rodata`, `.bss` sections.

Comment: Try this one http://ideone.com/HLfMG3

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct link? Nothing's changed from the linker script I'm currently using.

Comment: Yeah, it's correct, I just removed some ".", e.g. `*(.text.*)` became `*(.text)`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that. Thank you for your efforts, however the .axf file still contains no program headers. I'm really at a loss as to what to do now.

Comment: But now there are `.text`, etc. sections in the `.axf` file and `objcopy` produces a non-empty binary, right? If not, I ain't got other ideas :)

Comment: Unfortunately the binary is still empty. I'll open another question about the linker script not working. Thank you very much for your efforts, @chill!